# javascript - How i can get the data as Global Variable

Tags: javascript, async-await, global-variables

```
let data;
async function getData()
{
    let response = await fetch('http://~~~');
    data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

getData().then(data => console.log("bbbbb",data));

console.log("aaaaa",data);
```

this is my javascript code.
I want to know how to receive data as a global variable.
(bbbbb is successd, but aaaaa is not sucessed)

Comment: what problem actually you faced?

Answer (score 0):

```
let globalData;
async function getData()
{
    let response = await fetch('http://~~~');
    globalData = response.yourData;
}

getData(); 
// even you dont need this thing to do. 
// getData().then(data => console.log("bbbbb",data));

console.log("aaaaa", globalData);
```

By this, `globalData` variable is global now. and you can get data by `globalData`.

Comment: thank you. but when i use this code, console.log("aaaaa", globalData); is "aaaaa Promise {<pending>}", not my data.. why?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data;
async function getData()
{
    let response = await fetch('http://~~~');
    data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

getData()

console.log("aaaaa",data);
```

Anything outside you function scope can be considered as global.
Here data is a `global variable`

Comment: he cannot get data properly on last console. because, `getData().then(data => console.log("bbbbb",data));` this line change the value of data.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that. Only focused on the question about global variable